# Flutter app works on emulator but not phone when posting CSV to Flask API. How can I troubleshoot?

Tags: flutter, dart, flask

### Flutter app on phone failing to communicate with Flask server via USB

I'm encountering an issue where my Flutter app, which successfully communicates with a Flask server on an Android emulator, fails to do so when running on an actual phone connected through USB.

**Context:**

- **Flask server:**

  - Running within a virtual environment.
  - Has a POST API endpoint `/predict/plot` that accepts CSV files.
  - Returns a base64-encoded image string based on the CSV data.
- **Flutter app:**

  - Picks a CSV file using a file picker.
  - Posts the file to the Flask server's API.
  - Displays the received image after decoding it.

**Relevant code:**

**Flutter code (uploadCSV function):**

```
    var dio = Dio();
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path ?? " ");
      String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
      String filePath = file.path;
      FormData data = FormData.fromMap(
          {'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: fileName)});
      try {
        var response = await dio.post("http://10.0.2.2:5000/predict/plot",
            data: data, onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
          print('$sent  $total');
        });
        _imagebase64 = jsonDecode(response.toString())['image'];
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    } else {
      print("Response is null");
    }
  }
```

**Server-side code (Flask app):**

```
import joblib
import ast
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import base64
app = Flask(__name__)
# Your Flask routes go here
'''
model = joblib.load('model_filename.joblib')

@app.route('/predict/los', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
 #input_string = request.form.get('user_input')
 data = request.get_json()
 input_string = data.get('pred', 'No message received')
 feature_vector = ast.literal_eval(input_string)[0] 
 input = [feature_vector]
 print(input)
 numpy_array = np.array(input, dtype=float)
 output = model.predict(numpy_array)
 print(output)
 '''
 #return f"{output}"
'''
 response_data = {'status': 'success', 'prediction': output[0]}
 return jsonify(response_data)
'''
plt.switch_backend('Agg')
@app.route('/predict/plot', methods=['POST'])
def plot():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        obj = {"status": "fail", "message": 'No file part'}
        return jsonify(obj)

    file = request.files['file']

    # Validate file type
    if file.filename.endswith('.csv'):
        # Process CSV data
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        # Create a simple plot
        data = df['Diseases']
        column_data = {}
        #plot
        for row in data:
                value = row[0]
                if value in column_data:
                    column_data[value] += 1
                else:
                    column_data[value] = 1

            # Generate a bar chart
        categories = list(column_data.keys())
        counts = list(column_data.values())

        plt.bar(categories, counts)
        plt.xlabel('Categories')
        plt.ylabel('Count')
        plt.title('Bar Chart')

        # Convert the plot to a base64-encoded image
        plot_image_base64 = plot_to_base64(plt)

        # Close the plot to release resources
        plt.close()

        # Return the base64-encoded image as part of the JSON response
        obj = {"status": "success", "location": df.loc[0, 'Location'], "image": plot_image_base64}
        print(obj)
        return jsonify(obj)
    else:
        obj = {"status": "fail", "message": 'Invalid file type. Please upload a CSV file'}
        return jsonify(obj)

def plot_to_base64(plt_obj):
    # Save the plot to a BytesIO object
    plot_bytes = BytesIO()
    plt_obj.savefig(plot_bytes, format='png')
    plot_bytes.seek(0)

    # Convert the plot to a base64-encoded image
    plot_base64 = base64.b64encode(plot_bytes.read()).decode('utf-8')
    return plot_base64

# @app.route('/')
# def home():
#     print("i am here")
#     # Render the HTML form 
#     return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**Troubleshooting attempts:**

- Modified the host address in the Flutter app to the PC's IP address.
- Encountered errors like "connection timed out" and "socket exception."

**Request for assistance:**

How can I troubleshoot the issue and enable successful communication between the Flutter app and Flask server on the physical phone? This may involve:

- Identifying the root cause of the connection failure.
- Verifying network connectivity and firewall settings.
- Configuring CORS if necessary.
- Implementing proper error handling in the Flutter app.
- Suggesting additional debugging strategies.

**Additional information:**

- **Device and environment:**

  - Phone model and OS version.
  - Development environment details (IDE, Flutter version).
- **Full error messages:**

  - Including any logs or console output.

Modified the host address in the Flutter app to the PC's IP address.
Encountered errors like "connection timed out" and "socket exception."

Comment: Have you run your question through some LLM? Because half of it is gibberish and more like instructions it gave you to formulate your problem. Also, if you cannot reach your laptop/PC, try to ping it via another pc/mac at the same port to see if you can even reach it. If not then the issue probably lies with the host machine. Please review your question and post properly.

Comment: Does USB create a network device on the phone? You may need to check that - I wonder if it would only have access to the internet via Wi-Fi or mobile data. If that is so you'll need to expose your dev backend via an internet-connected proxy.